# How do I get textbox values from a gridview template field using jQuery.

Tags: jquery, textbox, return-value

I want to get textbox values from a gridview template field using jQuery.

Example:

> ID -- Name --- Age
>
> 1 --- Hung ---- Textbox has value : 20
>
> 2 --- John ---- Texbox has value : 19

How do I get the textbox values 20 or 19 (depending upon clicking) when I click the first or second row of textboxes using jQuery?

Thanks all!

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example row of code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a jquery grid (jQgrid, INGrid etc).. then the methods to access the field values comes as part of the api.

if you have a table & want to access the data then you can say.

```
$(':text").click(function(){

alert($(this).val());
// do something with the field data.
// here $(this) refers to the field on which the user clicked on.

});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: can u tell me onething how to get outside of this ($(this).val()) value

Comment: var val; $(':text").click(function(){
    
    val=$(this).val());
    // do something with the field data.
    // here $(this) refers to the field on which the user clicked on.
    
    });alert(val); i have modified this scripts but i didnt get val value outside of function

Comment: try adding a simple `alert()` message insode the function, this should let you know if the function was called..
also you should place the function code inside a `$(document).ready(function(){
// place function code here
});` this would get the browser to register the click event handler & you'd get the value.. also don't forget to add the alert function to verify if the function is being called or not.